# playwright._impl._api_types.Error: spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: playwright

runtime environment

> Windows 10 Enterprise Edition, 32-bit

> Python-3.7.9 32-bit

> playwright==1.15.3

my codes

```
# main.py
if __name__ == '__main__':

    from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto("http://playwright.dev")
        print(page.title())
        browser.close()
```

exception stack

```
C:\Users\yiguo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:/Users/yiguo/Desktop/ygmr-rpa/client/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yiguo/Desktop/ygmr-rpa/client/main.py", line 35, in <module>
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
  File "C:\Users\yiguo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_generated.py", line 11173, in launch
    firefoxUserPrefs=mapping.to_impl(firefox_user_prefs),
  File "C:\Users\yiguo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_sync_base.py", line 111, in _sync
    return task.result()
  File "C:\Users\yiguo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_browser_type.py", line 88, in launch
    return from_channel(await self._channel.send("launch", params))
  File "C:\Users\yiguo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 39, in send
    return await self.inner_send(method, params, False)
  File "C:\Users\yiguo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 57, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: spawn UNKNOWN
=========================== logs ===========================
<launching> C:\Users\yiguo\AppData\Local\ms-playwright\chromium-920619\chrome-win\chrome.exe --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --user-data-dir=C:\Users\yiguo\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright_chromiumdev_profile-WNIh91 --remote-debugging-pipe --headless --hide-scrollbars --mute-audio --blink-settings=primaryHoverType=2,availableHoverTypes=2,primaryPointerType=4,availablePointerTypes=4 --no-sandbox --no-startup-window
============================================================
```

Thank you!

I've tried `playwright==1.19.0`, It was wrong of a different kind

```
�ð汾�� C:\Users\yiguo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\playwright\driver\node.exe �������е� Windows �汾�����ݡ���鿴�������ϵͳ��Ϣ��Ȼ����ϵ��������ߡ�
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yiguo/Desktop/ygmr-rpa/client/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    with sync_playwright() as p:
  File "C:\Users\yiguo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_context_manager.py", line 71, in __enter__
    playwright = self._playwright
AttributeError: 'PlaywrightContextManager' object has no attribute '_playwright'
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<Connection.run.<locals>.init() running at C:\Users\yiguo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py:179> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x08FC7CB0>()]>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your CMD and enter playwright install
Then restart vscode and run this code again

Comment: This module operates twice,
The first time: pip install playwright
The second time: playwright install
I guess you may not have performed the second operation